# Unable to open Modal using JS Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I've been fiddling with the codes the last few days. It's from an old project that I had to modify.

Scripts

```
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js'></script> 
<script src="/lib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
@*<script src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/date.js"></script>*@

<script src="/wijmo/controls/wijmo.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/wijmo/controls/wijmo.input.min.js"></script>
<script src="/wijmo/controls/wijmo.grid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/wijmo/controls/wijmo.chart.min.js"></script>
<link href="/wijmo/styles/wijmo.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
@*<link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" /> --- this S.O.B will make things white. Big "NO, NO" *@
```

Modal:

```
<!-- Test Modal-->
<div class="modal fade" id="TestModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <!--Modal Header-->
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
                    &times;
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Test</h4>
            </div>
            <!--Modal Body-->
            <div class="modal-body">
                <dl class="dl-horizontal">
                    <dt>Branch Code</dt>
                    <dd>
                        <input class="form-control" id="BC" type="text" />
                    </dd>
                    <dt>Branch</dt>
                    <dd>
                        <input class="form-control" id="B" type="text" />
                    </dd>
                    <dt>Company ID</dt>
                    <dd>
                        <input class="form-control" id="CID" type="text" />
                    </dd>
                </dl>
            </div>
            <!--Modal Footer-->
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" id="TestEdit" onclick="CmdBranchEditOk_OnClick()">
                Ok
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal" id="TestModalCancel">
                Cancel
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript Function:

```
<Script>
    @*Test Function*@
    function OpenModal() {
        $('#TestModal').modal('show');

        document.getElementById('BC').value = "Test";
        document.getElementById('B').value = "Test";
        document.getElementById('CID').value = "Test";

    }
</script>
```

Trigger(Button):

```
<button style="float:left" id="CmdAddBranch" type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="OpenModal()">Open Modal</button>
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: What is the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

check your console you have a java script error

```
TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null
document.getElementById('B').value = "Test";
```

chick this **id=B"** you missing **"** for attribute in this line

```
 <input class="form-control" id=B" type="text" />
```

replace it with

```
 <input class="form-control" id="B" type="text" />
```

Comment: Tried it again after fixing the id line. Still nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in jquery part..see this **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/sheshu036/c7y8nzoo/)**

```
 $('#CmdAddBranch').click(function(){

    $('#TestModal').modal('show');
    $('#BC').val("Test") ;
       $('#B').val("Test");
    $('#CID').val("Test");
});
```